# FeatureClassToNumPyArray/other ArcMap functions in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, arcmap

I would like to know, what is the equivalent of ArcPy's FeatureClassToNumPyArray which does what the name suggests (grabs attribute table fields, length, area, x , y, etc and loads it to a structured numpy array)?

QGIS version 3.12, Python version 3.7.6

Answer (score 2):

You will want to convert your featureclass to a Geopandas [geodataframe](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/data_structures.html#geodataframe). Geopandas grabs all the attributes and assigns a `geometry` field in one line using [`geopandas.read_file()`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.read_file.html). Once your featureclass has been converted to a geodataframe you can do a variety of spatial operations using Geopandas and countless attribute manipulations using standard Pandas

For example:

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file('/path/to/your/geodatabase.gdb', driver='FileGDB', layer='featureclass')
print(gdf)
```

---

```
     Id  ...                                           geometry
0     0  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((574822.862 463991.125, 575346....
1     0  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((-315513.947 427995.640, -31580...
2     0  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((-130317.033 1186430.700, -1304...
3     0  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((-271811.830 1121101.707, -2720...
4     0  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((-290662.084 1149661.257, -2909...
..   ..  ...                                                ...
107   0  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((265211.850 1218091.959, 260277...
108   0  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((191176.499 1215622.191, 191370...
109   0  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((48520.918 1136776.587, 48569.5...
110   0  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((28547.064 1136665.373, 33540.5...
111   0  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((-70893.287 1178620.142, -70964...
```

Answer (score 0):

So copying and pasting from the PyQGIS cookbook I have a function that gets the attribute table as a pandas dataframe, the geometry bit could easily be uncommented and loaded into the DF as well.

```
import pandas as pd
def getAttem(layer= iface.activeLayer()):
    """retrieve every feature with its attributes"""
    fldz = [field.name() for field in layer.fields()]
    attrz = []
    features = layer.getFeatures()
    for feature in features:
        # print("Feature ID: ", feature.id())
        # # fetch geometry
        # # show some information about the feature geometry
        # geom = feature.geometry()
        # geomSingleType = QgsWkbTypes.isSingleType(geom.wkbType())
        # if geom.type() == QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry:
        #     # the geometry type can be of single or multi type
        #     if geomSingleType:
        #         x = geom.asPoint()
        #         print("Point: ", x)
        #     else:
        #         x = geom.asMultiPoint()
        #         print("MultiPoint: ", x)
        # elif geom.type() == QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry:
        #     if geomSingleType:
        #         x = geom.asPolyline()
        #         print("Line: ", x, "length: ", geom.length())
        #     else:
        #         x = geom.asMultiPolyline()
        #         print("MultiLine: ", x, "length: ", geom.length())
        # elif geom.type() == QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry:
        #     if geomSingleType:
        #         x = geom.asPolygon()
        #         print("Polygon: ", x, "Area: ", geom.area())
        #     else:
        #         x = geom.asMultiPolygon()
        #         print("MultiPolygon: ", x, "Area: ", geom.area())
        # else:
        #     print("Unknown or invalid geometry")
        # fetch attributes
        attrz += [feature.attributes()]
        # attrs is a list. It contains all the attribute values of this feature
        #print(attrs)
    attr = pd.DataFrame(attrz,columns = fldz)
    return attr
print(getAttem())
```

Comment: If you're using pandas anyway, try geopandas and just load the geometry and attributes in one line - [`geopandas.read_file(your_featureclass)`](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.read_file.html).